# Laravel IoC outside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, pimple

I am using this [repo](https://github.com/laracasts/Eloquent-Outside-of-Laravel) as the basis for a new CLI PHP project using Eloquent as the ORM.

When you create the new Eloquent `capsule` you have the option to `setAsGlobal` which makes the DB capsule accessible from anywhere in the code.

Does that mean there's a Laravel Container being used? Or is this just affecting the DB object?

I'd been using [pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) as a container, but if Laravel already has a container I can bind to via Eloquent, that would be a lot simpler-- I want to bind a log writer, the Eloquent capsule, and probably a settings object to the global container so I can access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not use Laravels Container. If you look at the method in the trait: ([github.com](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/CapsuleManagerTrait.php#L43-L46))

```
public function setAsGlobal()
{
    static::$instance = $this;
}
```

You can see that it just sets a static property on the class containing the current instance so it will be reused for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Hope it helps.

https://gist.github.com/reinink/9112262

```
"require":
{
    "illuminate/container": "4.0.*@dev",
}
```